# Publish message to kafka via http

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm new with kafka and I'm trying to publish data from external application via http but I cannot find the way to do this.

I already created a topic in kafka and test it producing and consuming the message but I don't know how to insert/publish message via http, I tried to invoke the following url to retrieve the topics but it does not retrieve any data http://servername:2181/topics/

I'm using cloudera 5.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to your topics, if it was already created, using [APIs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerapi). The easy way...(see [client list](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients))

Or see [Connects Config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs) to manage connectors by REST (rest.host.name, rest.port parameters). But only connectors...
To consume or produce message in a topic, use a middleware. IT is more feaseble.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the open source [Kafka REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html) from Confluent. It does exactly what you want.

You can get it [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest), or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).